# ConfigurationProperties in Spring 2.5.3

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to make a `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated class, but I'm getting `Cannot resolve symbol 'ConfigurationProperties'` on `import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties`.
However if I set the Spring version to 2.4.0 the annotation and import work. What is the correct way of declaring ConfigurationProperties in Spring 2.5.3?

EDIT: As requested, dependencies of pom.xml:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-lib</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>test-auth</artifactId>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-common</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The import and annotation work fine if I put `org.springframework.boot - spring-boot` to version 2.4.0.

Comment: Is it a maven project? Care to post your pom.xml? If you run `mvn clean package` does it finish successfully?

Comment: Yes, the build is successful, no problems there. Added the pom.xml.

Comment: If it compiles fine via command line then I guess its an IDE bug? Have you tried to refresh/invalidate your IDE's cache e.g. Intellij Idea: File->Invalidate Caches... ?

Comment: Invalidating Caches did not solve the problem, however I will continue and try to see if the app will work despite the IDE error. Thank you.

Comment: I've updated my IDE and the problem was solved.